# UIWebView throwing exception on LoadRequest

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have the following code trying to load a web page on my app:

```
Console.WriteLine("login view class");
NSUrl url = new NSUrl("http://deekor.com");
NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
loginWebView.LoadRequest(request);
```

The last line:

```
loginWebView.LoadRequest(request);
```

is throwing an `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` exception.

`loginWebView` is a `UIWebView`

Whats going wrong?

**Edit**

I think I was forgetting this line: `loginWebView = new UIWebView();` After adding it the exception is gone... however the page is not loading..

Looking at the locals in debug I see `loginWebView` is set to `null` before I call `loginWebView = new UIWebView();`. Do I want to be creating a new one like this, or is something wrong with my outlet?

**LoginViewController.Designer.cs**

[image]

**StoryBoard**

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but `TargetInvocationException` means that during reflection, there was an exception during an invocation of a method.  The inner exception would provide the real details of the error.

Comment: @KirkWoll I just edited my post. Does that seem right? Any idea why its not loading now?

Comment: Have you added loginWebView to its parent so that its visible?

Comment: @Jason I dragged a uiwebview on to the storyboard and created an outlet for it called `loginWebView` if thats what you are asking. Sorry I am pretty new to this.

Comment: @Jason I further updated my post

Comment: Could you try and catch the exception, to see the stacktrace and inner exception?

Comment: @CasperSkoubo the exception was `System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` the exception was gone after I added the `loginWebView = new UIWebView();` line. However its not showing the web page now. Im thinking maybe because I am calling new its being set to the wrong object?  
`

Comment: @Deekor Ok thanks. Just some things you could check: Are you sure the outlet is correctly set? Have you tried to hook up and see if there are any load errors? - there might be a connection issue, since its just blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Deekor,

I loaded up a new project, and I tried to make exactly what you were making. I ran into the same issue if I followed these steps:

1. Create a new iPhone, single view, storyboard project.
2. Open up the storyboard file and drag a UIWebView onto the UIViewController that is created automatically in the new project.
3. Go back to Xamarin Studio and in the LoginViewController.cs file that was created for me, try to put in the loginWebView.Request code.

This doesnt work, as you noticed because the web view is null. It should not be. I don't know why, but there was also missing methods in that LoginViewController.cs file that is auto created. I could not override ViewDidLoad() which is where you want to be. Even though the class is inheriting from UIViewController, the override was just not available. So here is how I fixed the problem:

1. Delete the auto generated UIViewController in the Storyboard.
2. Delete the auto generated class that came with it (LoginViewController.cs)
3. Now in the storyboard, drag in a new UIViewController.
4. In the Custom Class box in interface builder, enter your class name: LoginViewController.
5. Go back to Xamarin Studio, and let it sync up and create the files for you again.
6. No go back to Interface Builder/Xcode and drag a UIWebView onto that new LoginViewController you created in step 3.
7. Drag your outlet for the loginWebView just as you did before.
8. Go back to Xamarin Studio and let it sync up.
9. Open your LoginViewController.cs file and now you can override ViewDidLoad().
10. Now you can simply have this:

    ```
    public partial class LoginViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public LoginViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            loginWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("http://deekor.com")));
        }
    }
    ```

I don't know why sometimes the auto-generated files from a new project act strange, but basically all I did was delete what it created, and manually add the same thing again and then it worked. The web view being null when you launched is what made me think something was wrong. Please comment if something is confusing, I will do my best to explain better if I can. I did get this working following the steps above. In the image attached you can see it running in the simulator, showing your page. [image: uiwebview loading the page]

Comment: Aha! My controller was created like you suggested after the auto generations. However I just noticed the class header was generated as `public partial class LoginViewController : UIView` not `public partial class LoginViewController : UIViewController` changing that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Just to see what is happening try the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("login view class");
var webView = new UIWebView(this.View.Frame);
this.View.Add(webView);
NSUrl url = new NSUrl("http://deekor.com"); 
NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
webView.LoadRequest(request);
```

If that works it means it is an issue with how the WebView has been added to your Storyboard and then connected as an outlet...

Comment: Nope that still didn't load the page. I have updated my question with screenshots of my outlet.

Comment: have you tried this on multiple dev machines? does the simulator definitely have internet access? I tried my code above and it worked fine.

Comment: I have not tried other machines, but it definitely has interent access, I'm doing a `httprequest` just fine in other parts of the code. Does my outlet look right in the screenshot above?

Comment: Yes it looks fine, it is unlikely your outlet as the code above i added does not work.

Comment: The only reason I thought it was the outlet is because `loginWebView` is set to null before I call `new UIWebView();` shouldn't it already be set to an instance of an object?

Comment: Yes completely, you should not have to instantiate a ui object created in a storyboard. It seems strange though how the code above also doesn't work.